# Recursive values based on a combination of previous values in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I have a dataset which contains firm's performance measures. My goal is to create an "Aspiration Level" variable that is built as described below:

For each firm, first aspiration level equals to earliest performance measure. Next, aspiration values are a combination of previous performance and previous aspirations. If a performance value is missing, the the latest non-missing value should be used.

Formally:

[image]

For a random example dataset:

```
> df <- data.table("year"=2001:2009, "perf"=c(NA,12,36,NA,NA,44,48,NA,68))
> df
   year perf
1: 2001   NA
2: 2002   12
3: 2003   36
4: 2004   NA
5: 2005   NA
6: 2006   44
7: 2007   48
8: 2008   NA
9: 2009   68
```

My desired outcome is:

```
> df
   year perf      Asp
1: 2001   NA       NA
2: 2002   12 12.00000
3: 2003   36 12.00000
4: 2004   NA 33.60000
5: 2005   NA 35.76000
6: 2006   44 35.97600
7: 2007   48 43.19760
8: 2008   NA 47.51976
9: 2009   68 47.95198
```

I have currently written a for loop that gives me the desired outcome, which I can iterate over multiple firms in my dataset:

```
> alpha = 0.9
> myfn <- function(x) {
+   x$HA <- NA
+   perf1 <- x$perf[!is.na(x$perf)][1]
+   indx <- which(x$perf==perf1)
+   x$HA[indx] <- x$perf[indx]
+   for (i in (indx+1):nrow(x)) {
+     abc <- head(x$perf[1:i-1],(i-1))
+     x$HA[i] <- alpha*tail(abc[!is.na(abc)],1) + (1-alpha)*x$HA[i-1]
+     }
+   ;
+   return(as.vector(x$HA))
+ }
> 
> myfn(df)
[1]       NA 12.00000 12.00000 33.60000 35.76000 35.97600 43.19760 47.51976 47.95198
```

However, I'm sure there's a way more efficient way to do this. Preferably, I'm looking for a data.table solution so I can gain efficiency iterating the solution over about 100k firms.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursively defined series are difficult to do efficiently in R. In this situation I would quickly write an Rcpp function:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
 NumericVector calcAsp (const NumericVector Perf, double c) {
   double n = Perf.length();
   NumericVector Asp(n);
   
   double s = 0;
   double perf;
   
   while (NumericVector::is_na(Perf(s))) {
     Asp(s) = NA_REAL;
     s++;
   }     
   Asp(s) = Perf(s);
   
   for (double i = s + 1;  i < n; ++i ) {
     if (! NumericVector::is_na(Perf(i - 1))) perf = Perf(i - 1);
     Asp(i) = c * perf + (1 - c) * Asp(i - 1);  
   } 

  return Asp;
 }
")

df[, Asp := calcAsp(perf, 0.9)]
#   year perf      Asp
#1: 2001   NA       NA
#2: 2002   12 12.00000
#3: 2003   36 12.00000
#4: 2004   NA 33.60000
#5: 2005   NA 35.76000
#6: 2006   44 35.97600
#7: 2007   48 43.19760
#8: 2008   NA 47.51976
#9: 2009   68 47.95198
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but thought it'd be interesting to see the performance difference between the two methods. This is done by implementing it on a set of ~350K observations of firms:

Results really speak for themselves!

```
> Roland<- function()
+    df[nmisval>1,`:=`(
+    HA_Rec = calcAsp(ROA, 0.9)
+    )
+    ,by = .(gvkey)]
> 
> lovestackflow <- function()
+    df[nmisval>1,`:=`(
+    HA_Rec = myfn(.SD)
+    )
+    ,by = .(gvkey)]
> 
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=3L,
+                                lovestackflow(), Roland())
Unit: milliseconds
            expr        min          lq        mean     median          uq        max neval
 lovestackflow() 17725.0021 18178.14270 18441.86683 18631.2833 18800.29920 18969.3151     3
        Roland()    62.5675    64.10295    74.92807    65.6384    81.10835    96.5783     3
```

Thanks for the help!